# Moment generating function and exponentially decaying tails of probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory

This is a follow-up to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80674/physical-meaning-of-higher-moments-their-values-and-their-existence).

Suppose I have a mean-zero symmetrically-distributed random variable $X$ over the support $\mathbb{R}$. If $X$ has a moment-generating function $M_X(t)$ that is smooth around 0, $X$ has an exponentially decaying tail probability, by Chernoff bound (Lemma 11.9.1 in Cover and Thomas's "Elements of Information Theory" 2nd edition).

Now, suppose that $X$ has an $M_X(t)$ that is not smooth around 0.  Suppose that $\mathbf{E}[X^k]=\infty$ for all even $k>n$, where $n$ is a positive integer.  Is there $X$ that has exponentially-decaying tail probability in that case?  Or would the tail probability always be a power-law?

Also, what happens to the tail if $M_X(t)$ is not defined, i.e. the integral in the transform diverges?

**EDITS**: Clarified the question based on helpful comments from @cardinal.

Comment: A somewhat pedantic response to your question is that no such random variable $X$ can exist in the first place based on the set of conditions you've placed on it. Do you see why? (**Hint**: Consider $k > n$ where $k$ is odd.)

Comment: Hmmm...  I see what you are saying.  But does this mean that any symmetric zero-mean $X$ has to have all finite moments?  Or is there a symmetric zero-mean $X$ that has all the moments but for which $M_X(t)$ is not smooth around 0?  Which condition should I weaken?

Comment: No, quite the opposite. A symmetric distribution about zero need not have any (raw) odd moments at all, but all (raw) even moments will exist, even if they are not finite.

Comment: I think I am confused about what it means by "not having moment $\mu_n$".  I interpret that only as "$\mu_n=\infty$".  That is, my interpretation of "having moments" means "having finite momemts, possibly equal to zero".  Would removing "Suppose that $\mathbf{E}[X_k]=\infty$ for all $k>n$, where $n$ is a positive integer" put more sense into my question?  I'm mainly interested in what happens for $X$ with $M_X(t)$ that is not smooth around zero.

Comment: And I was confused by your first comment because Student's t has finite moments up to its degree of freedom and further even moments are infinite or the integral in the mgf diverges for odd ones.  Anyway, my bad -- I've edited my question.

Comment: @Bullmoose You should be talking about characteristic function, not the moment generating function, this does not exists if $\mathbb{E}(\vert X \vert^k ) = \infty$ for all $k>n$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that "exponentially decaying tail probability" means that $P(|X| > t) \le C e^{-\epsilon t}$ for some $C, \epsilon$.  Any such random variable has finite moments of all orders.  This follows from the formula
$$E[|X|^p] = \int_0^\infty p t^{p-1} P(|X| > t) dt$$
which you can prove with Fubini's theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thanks!  That's the result I've been looking for.

Comment: @Bullmoose: Note that this is the converse of the statement you originally quoted in another question. So, just be sure it actually *is* the result you were looking for. :)

Comment: @cardinal Basically, I wanted to know whether not having finite moments of all orders implies that the tail probabilities do not decay exponentially.  I think this answer answers it (as a contrapositive.)  The statement I made in the comment to the other question states that if MGF is smooth around 0 then its tails decay exponentially, and it has all finite moments.  I understand that having finite moments of all orders doesn't necessarily result in having exponential tails  (the lognormal example), but for my problem it suffices to state that having a smooth MGF implies moments and exp-tails.

Comment: @Bullmoose: I was referring to the following statement of yours in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80674/physical-meaning-of-higher-moments-their-values-and-their-existence): *I've heard somewhere that all finite moments of A with support R means that the tails of A decay exponentially. Is that true?*

Comment: Ahh, right.  And that statement was shown to not be true.  :)